# when executing batch file cmd only outputs so much

Tags: batch, cmd.exe

I write simple batch files to automate simple processes along the lines of this

```
for /r %%n in (*.wav) do del "%%n"
PAUSE
```

when i execute this command the cmd quickly scrolls through all the files it's deleting, however sometimes the total files executed exceeds what cmd will allow me to review.  I do not need to make the batch output the list to a file I just want to be able to view all the files deleted by the batch in the cmd.  Is there a way to expand the number of lines shown by the cmd?

Comment: you could add `>Log.txt` to the end of the for command to send the output to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

1. (dir /p *.wav) && (del *.wav)
2. increase buffer size.. right click on title bar and then:

[image]